# Power BI - Pulling the last transaction date from one table to another table

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables ItemTransactions and CI_Items. I'm trying to pull the last transaction date for each item code from the ItemTransaction table to the CI_Items table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRNTH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEeBC.png)

I tried these:
Last Transaction = LASTDATE(ItemTransaction[Transaction Date]), I received a circular dependency error
Last Transaction = MAXA(ItemTransaction[Transaction Date]), I received the date of 2/5/24 on every item, which I know isn't true.
I've tried many other things but didn't keep track of them all.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!